# PHP date_sunset is off

Tags: php

I'm trying to find what time the sun will set on any given day so I'm using PHP's `date_sunset` function.

```
date_sunset($date, SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, $location['lat'], $location['lng'], 90, $offset);
```

The times given seem off by a few minutes compared to what sunset logs state, and I think it's because I'm setting the zenith to 90. I'm not sure what this number is and I'm only using 90 because that's what the demo on in the PHP manual used.

What is this number and how do I more accurately set the sunset time?